# Verb, but no subject, after 'such as'?

Tags: grammaticality

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p. 55.

> 3.23. The Ontario Court of Appeal suggested in *Tilden Rent-A-Car Co v Clendenning* (1978)
>   that the rule was too absolute, and chose to distinguish *L’Estrange*. There, the defendant
>   rented a car and signed the contract without reading it. On the back of the contract, in
>   fine and faint print, was a clause seeking to limit the claimant’s liability. The court, applying
>   orthodox offer and acceptance principles, held that a signature will only indicate
>   acceptance of a term where it is reasonable for the other party to believe that the offeree
>   really did agree to the term in question. While a court should be reluctant to find that a
>   signature did not indicate acceptance of a particular term (otherwise commercial uncertainty
>   would result), on the facts the term had not been accepted:
>
> > In ordinary commercial practice where there is frequently a sense of formality in the
> >     transaction, and where there is a full opportunity for the parties to consider the terms of
> >     the proposed contract submitted for signature, it might well be safe to assume that the
> >     party who attaches his signature to the contract intends by so doing to acknowledge his
> >     acquiescence to its terms, and that the other party entered into the contract upon that
> >     belief. This can hardly be said, however, where the contract is entered into **in circumstances
> >     such as were present** in this case.

What are some formal terms describing this syntax? How can a verb follow **such as** without another subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could also say:

... entered into in such circumstances as were present in this case.

So I believe the explanation is not ellipsis but inversion. *Such* here is adjectival and "as were present" is an adverbial clause

Comment: I see no inversion.

Comment: From _in **such** circumstances as were present_ to _in circumstances **such** as were present_ is probably the easiest way to interpret this sentence.

Comment: @tunny: What *do* you see, a relative pronoun *such*?

Comment: @oerkelens Thanks, but I don't understand your comment. Why did you bold **such**? Is your comment just the reverse direction of TRomano's answer?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit my comment illustrates the inversion that TRomano mentions and that tunny didn't see. _Such_ was bolded to illustrate that _circumstances_ and _such_ swapped places in the sentence. My comment underlines why I think TRomano's answer deserved my +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this usage of "such as" is short for "such as [aforementioned subject]."

This sentence is equivalent to:

> This can hardly be said, however, where the contract is entered into, in circumstances **such as** **those that** were present in this case.

Comment: Thanks, but the sentence itself does NOT contain **those that**? Why can you add them to the sentence yourself?