# Verb, but no subject, after 'such ... as'?

Tags: grammaticality, legalese

Source: p 52, *Criminal Law: The Basics*, 1 ed (2009), by Herring

> HOMICIDE ACT 1957, SECTION 2
>   Where a person kills or is a party to the killing of another, he shall
>   not be convicted of murder if he was suffering from **such** abnormality
>   of mind (whether arising from a condition of arrested or retarded
>   development of mind or any inherent causes or induced by
>   disease or injury) **as** substantially impaired his mental responsibility
>   for his acts and omissions in doing or being a party to the killing.

Please observe that this question differs from [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/38616/8712), because herein a subject splits **such as**. What are some formal terms describing this issue? How can a verb follow **such ... as** without another subject?
This sounds wrong to me, so would someone please explain the grammar and also the meaning?

Comment: [such .... as] is the subject of _impaired_. I'm not sure what you are asking exactly. Do you understand the build-up of this sentence? "It is hard to find such apples as I like eating."

Comment: It's easy to find or compose such sentences as illustrate this usage. Where *illustrate this usage* is a verb phrase describing something *sentences like that* do, in the same way as in OP's excerpt, *impaired his responsibility* is something *an abnormality like that* does.

Answer (score 2):

## Grammatical structure

I'm going to make a simpler sentence that has the same structure, in order to make it easier to explain:

> I had trouble finding such cake as would satisfy all my fussy relatives.

Here, *such cake* is the direct object of *finding*. Or, to be more correct, the whole phrase *such cake as would satisfy all my fussy relatives* is the direct object of *finding*.

If we break that second phrase ("such cake as would satisfy all my fussy relatives") down further, we can see that *such cake* is the subject of *satisfy* and *my fussy relatives* is the direct object of it.

Or, pictorially:

[image: sentence-structure-diagram]

## Meaning

In terms of meaning, the above sentence means that the writer is having difficulty finding a cake that would satisfy all his or her relatives. The *such* simply relates the cake to the **condition** that the cake must fulfil (i.e. satisfying the relatives).

More examples:

- such embarrassment as completely prevented me leaving the house (= the embarrassment was such that I couldn't leave the house)
- such fear as froze him to the spot (the fear is a fear which fulfils the condition of freezing him to the spot)
- such quantities of food as made us all sick later (the quantity of food was such a quantity ("large quantity" is implied from context) that we all felt ill later)

## Your sentence

Now if we do the same thing with the more complicated sentence we can see that it is his abnormality of mind that is impairing his mental responsibility for his acts. In other words, the abnormality of mind fulfils the condition of substantially impairing his sense of mental responsibility for his acts. And, under that condition (having such an abnormality of mind), the perpetrator would not be convicted of murder - basically, because they didn't know what they were doing was wrong. However, if he *didn't* fulfil that condition, he could still be convicted of murder.

Comment: Not sure how clear the final paragraph is. I can possibly rephrase later when I have a bit more time.